# Extending a memory-mapped file in Python (Mac & Linux)

Tags: python, mmap

On Windows mmap'd files can be automatically extended on open, but this is not supported on UNIX-like systems:

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/mmap.html

I have an existing set of classes that provide an append-only journal in Python using mmap, but the file size is fixed to 64 MB:

https://github.com/cloudwall/serenity/blob/master/src/serenity/tickstore/journal.py

I'd like to revise

```py
    def _check_space(self, add_length: int):
        if self.mm.get_pos() + add_length >= self.max_size:
            raise NoSpaceException()
```

to automatically extend the underlying file and add another 64GB of space. In outline I think I know how to do this:

1. Unmap the file
2. seek to the end
3. append 64MB of zeroes
4. re-map the file

but am very wary that I'll corrupt a journal on restart if I don't execute this properly. (Note I have live-running services in Kubernetes that are collecting data 24x7.) Is this the right approach? Can you safely extend the file under a mmap region while running?

Comment: Hint: `truncate` can make files bigger, not just smaller.

Comment: Nice. truncate (the UNIX command) works for repairing journal files, so I'll just have to figure out how to automate that within journal.py.